# Edit bundle config class for newly implemented theme

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

When I try to bundle my CSS and javascript, my javascript and CSS effects do not seem to work. I am using the js files and CSS files normally as in ASP.NET Web Forms.

I have kept my CSS and js files only in below code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/css/adminlte.min.css">

<!-- REQUIRED SCRIPTS -->
<script src="~/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/dist/js/adminlte.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/dist/js/pages/dashboard3.js"></script>
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Here is the bundle config class

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
```

1. How can I bundle my js files and CSS files?
2. Also, I have referenced the jquery validate js file, still validation is not working in my pages. What is the problem?

Please see the attached image for file structure.

[image: My project file structure]

Comment: Have you remembered to register in the Application_Start of the global.asax?  And called `Scripts.Render()` from your layout file?

Comment: @DaveBarnett No I have not done that. But I don't think I have to register in Application_Start file too.

Comment: Ah because you've presumably done it in the start up.

Comment: @DaveBarnett Can you please tell me how can I solve my problem ?

Comment: I don't have time right now.  But if nobody else has by the time I get back to my computer later I will do.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is is how I would do it for your setup.

Make sure you have installed the nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.

Here is the edited BundleConfig

```
public static class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/allcss")
            .Include("~/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css")
            .Include("~/dist/css/adminlte.min.css"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/alljs")
            .Include("~/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js")
            .Include("~/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js")
            .Include("~/dist/js/adminlte.js")
            .Include("~/plugins/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.min.js")
            .Include("~/dist/js/pages/dashboard3.js"));
    }
}
```

The global.asax

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {           
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
       //other unrelated code            
    }      
}
```

Relevant parts of _Layout.cshtml

Note you don't have to put the Render calls in the _layout.cshtml but this is the standard place for most apps.

```
@using System.Web.Optimization

<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
<head>
       @Styles.Render("~/bundles/allcss")
</head>
<body>

   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/alljs")      
   @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

2. I believe you also need to put jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js after jquery.validate.js.  Ensure you have added the correct settings in your web.config

```xml
    <appSettings>  
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
        <!--other settings-->
    </appSettings>
```

See this for [more explanation](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc5-jquery-form-validator/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your solution helped me to understand the concept regarding bundles. Thank you very much!!!